# Set Right Alignment in JTable Column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am creating an application for a billing facility.  I want the amount column to display with right alignment.  How do I set the right alignment for a JTable column?

Answer (score 39):

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
```

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, just: a) *DON'T SHOUT* b) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them (you can edit your answer and fix both)

Comment: I found it working but only partially. 1) If you set the column renderer first and then the model, the model invalidate the already set renderer, make it `null`. 2) I am using Nimbus L&F, and the newly set renderer change the background color to be inconsistent with other cells. I may open a question about this issue.

Comment: +0 This solution is simple and works, yes, but please consider the solution from @trashgod,more elegant and works easy to extend, particular if you plan to sort

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
JTable tbl = new JTable(3,3) {
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderRight = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

    { // initializer block
        renderRight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer (int arg0, int arg1) {
        return renderRight;
    }
};
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using an initializer block in anonymous classes. Solves the lack of constructor, nicely.

Comment: -1 for short-circuiting all support for fine-grained renderer configuration of the table (by returning one-for-all) Also there is no need at all to subclass, instead use table/column's api to install custom renderer's as needed

Comment: An addition to kleopatra's comment as I'm currently doing the same thing as op: You can still kind of customize the renderer according to your needs with Emil's answer. `arg0` is the row and `arg1` is the column, so a simple e.g. `if(arg1==0)` lets you align all the cells in column 0 a certain way. I'm subclassing `JTable` anyway to set a custom color for specific cells (with `prepareRenderer`) and surprisingly they don't conflict - just don't return `null` (unless you want an exception). Plus, you don't have to set the column titles before doing it (like with sathya's accepted answer).

Answer (score 6):

See [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), noting "`Number` — rendered by a right-aligned label." Just have your `TableModel` return the correct class. As a concrete example, note that `Integer` is a `Number`, while examining the implementation of `getColumnClass()` in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55792917/230513), the zeroth `colIndex` returns `Object.class`, which is "rendered by a label that displays the object's string value." By default, the label is left-aligned.

```
switch (colIndex) {
    case 0: return Object.class;
    …
}
```

[image: left-aligned]

In contrast, `Integer.class` is "rendered by a right-aligned label."

```
switch (colIndex) {
    case 0: return Integer.class;
    …
}
```

[image: right-aligned]

These are examples of using [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13673688/230513) in the context of `JTable`.

Comment: Have you even tried this? this doesn't work. Even if it did, I still wouldn't really like this approach just because you're trying to trick the class into thinking you're using a certain Object type, which may have other consequences that go beyond just aligning text.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to get DefaultTableCellRenderer for table cells and call setHorizontalAlignment(alignment).

Example can be found on links:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-justify-data-in-a-jtable-cell/5032692/

http://www.coderanch.com/t/337549/GUI/java/align-data-columns-JTable

Comment: +1 I'm a little wary of articles that misspell `JTable`, but the sidebar show a complete example. :-)

Comment: class RightTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {    
  protected  RightTableCellRenderer() {   
    setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);  }   

i add this code, after that how can i set the renderer to my jtable column. 
     
}