# Set icon to each node in Jtree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode, treecellrenderer

I want to set a different icon for each node in my JTree component. I'm loading each node from a database using a `while` loop. I set each icon like a root, leaf, or parent. I set them as follows:

All my declarations are global:

```
private ResultSet myResultSet;
protected DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode,childNode,parent1,parent2;
```

This is how I set my nodes:

```
myResultSet=rtnNodes(); /*Method that returns a RS with my nodes*/
while(myResultSet.next()){
  switch(myResultSet.getInt(1)){  /*The first column is the type of node: root, parent, leaf...*/
    case 0: treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel((rootNode=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(myResultSet.getString(2)))); break;  /*root node*/
    case 1: case 4: parent1 = parent2 = makeNode(rootNode); break;  /*parent node*/
    case 2: makeNode(parent2); break;  /*leaf node*/
    case 3: parent2 = makeNode(parent1); break;  /*sub patern node*/
  } /*makeNode is the method where I create the nodes*/
}
```

The `makeNode` method is this:

```
public DefaultMutableTreeNode makeNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent){
  //The second column in the RS is the name of the node
  treeModel.insertNodeInto((childNode=new DefaultMutableTreeNode(myResultSet.getString(2))),parent,parent.getChildCount());
  return childNode;
}
```

After filling the `treemodel` with my nodes, I set the model to my JTree:

```
myJTree.setModel(treeModel);
myJTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
```

But the problem comes when I try to set the icons. I create a subclass called MyTreeRenderer, and I use this:

```
myJTree.setCellRenderer(new MyTreeRenderer());
```

But it doesn't set the icons as I want, the subclass is:

```
private ImageIcon root,parent,leaf;

public MyTreeRenderer() {
   root=setIcons(2);  /*setIcons is a method that I dont publish in this post, that helps me to set the path of the icons*/
   parent=setIcons(3);
   leaf=setIcons(4);
}

@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,Object value,boolean selected,boolean expanded,boolean leaf,int row,boolean hasFocus){               
   super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,value,selected,expanded,leaf,row,hasFocus);
   DefaultMutableTreeNode nodo = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
   TreeNode t = nodo.getParent();
   if(t!=null){
      setIcon(root);
   }
   return this;
}
```

How can I set the icon for each node without using his name? The code of the subclass, as is, set all the nodes with the same icon, and each time I select a node in the jtree, the `getTreeCellRendererComponent` runs, I don´t want this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can change default UI values for icons of `JTree` nodes without any custom renderer:

```
URL resource = logaff.class.getResource(IMAGE);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(resource);

UIManager.put("Tree.closedIcon", icon);
UIManager.put("Tree.openIcon", icon);
UIManager.put("Tree.leafIcon", icon);
```

or use something like next:

```
@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree,
    Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
    boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected,expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode nodo = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
        if (tree.getModel().getRoot().equals(nodo)) {
            setIcon(root);
        } else if (nodo.getChildCount() > 0) {
            setIcon(parent);
        } else {
            setIcon(leaf);
        }
        return this;
}
```

Also read about [rendering mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672980/difficulties-understanding-the-renderers-mechanism-of-swings-jtable-and-jtree).

Comment: WOW! I have two weeks searching an answer like that, a friend and me were reading a lot and all this time we were confused. To simple view the code is perfect, I'll test it and later  will tell you how it works.
Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Great solution! The icon size is 16x16 px² or any?

Answer (score 8):

You can use it, a shorter way. "tree" is my JTree component.

```
DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) tree.getCellRenderer();
Icon closedIcon = new ImageIcon("closed.png");
Icon openIcon = new ImageIcon("open.png");
Icon leafIcon = new ImageIcon("leaf.png");
renderer.setClosedIcon(closedIcon);
renderer.setOpenIcon(openIcon);
renderer.setLeafIcon(leafIcon);
```