# How can I solve problem with display in JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am a beginner in programming. I wanted to create total commander aplication. I had no bigger problem  but that one i can not solve.

To print my tree i use function getChild() from my class TreeConstructor that implements from JTreeModel. It works great but it prints all path to file or directory not only file name. I thought about creating myJTree class that will extend from JTree class and override function that prints the node but acctually i do not know where is this function and her name.

class TreeConstructor implements TreeModel {

```
//To constructor we need to give path
//From where it it starts painting a tree
protected File root;
public TreeConstructor(File root) { this.root = root; }

//Giving root of a tree
@Override
public Object getRoot() {
    return root;
}

//Function to change root 
public void rootChanger(Object parent) {
    this.root = (File)parent;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
    if((children.length<=index)||(children == null))return null;
    return new File((File)parent,children[index]);
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
    if(children == null) return 0;
    return children.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {  return ((File)node).isFile(); }

@Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
       String[] children = ((File)parent).list();
        if (children == null) return -1;
        String childname = ((File)child).getName();
        for(int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          if (childname.equals(children[i])) return i;
        }
        return -1;
}

@Override
public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {}

@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}

@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {}
```

It is my application:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AsiV.jpg

I will be grateful for your help Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Without further code example i suggest you look for the following:

1. Use the search function, you are not the first one with this problem :)

[Java JTree from directory (shows full path instead of just the name of the file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804035/java-jtree-from-directory-shows-full-path-instead-of-just-the-name-of-the-file)

2. Write your own renderer

Depending on your implementation it may be the easiest way to just write your own Render

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-swing/jtree-renderer.html

Answer (score 0):

As it already said, you need your own renderer. Something like this:

```
public class FileTreeRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded,
            boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        if (value instanceof File) {
            setText(((File) value).getName());
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

And then you need to set the renderer into your tree

```
tree.setCellRenderer(new FileTreeRenderer());
```

Also the methods defined in the TreeModel interface must be implemented to provide correct working of your JTree. Especially add/removeTreeModelListener. They are used to provide a possibility to notify tree when your model is changed (for example when user renames a node).

Comment: i commented below

Comment: For example you can make a new class file for the `FileTreeRenderer `. And then set the renderer for example after set of its model.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Panels extends JPanel{

    File f1 = new File("C:\\Users");

    public TreeConstructor model = new TreeConstructor(f1);

    public JTree tree = new JTree(model);

    public JTextField pathPlace = new JTextField(100);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);

    Panels(){

        pathPlace.setText("C:\\Users");

        tree.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getClickCount()==2) {      
                    System.out.println();
                    repaintingTree(pathPlace, tree, model);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        pathPlace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                repaintingTree(pathPlace, tree, model, pathPlace.getText());

            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(pathPlace,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void repaintingTree(JTextField pathPlace, JTree tree, TreeConstructor model){
        File place = new File(tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString());
        if(place.isDirectory()) {
            pathPlace.setText(tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString());
            model = new TreeConstructor(place);
            tree.setModel(model);
            tree.repaint();
    }}

    public static void repaintingTree(JTextField pathPlace, JTree tree, TreeConstructor model, String path){
        File place = new File(path);
        if(place.isDirectory()) {
            pathPlace.setText(path);
            model = new TreeConstructor(place);
            tree.setModel(model);
            tree.repaint();
            }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong directory");
        }
    }
```

here is code where i use JTree can I use your code to rendering with this ?
I do not understand it :/