# Changing the colour of specific index using JList

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlist, listcellrenderer

How can I change the colour of a specific index using JList, I manage to change the colour, but it changes the colour of the whole list and I need to be able to change a specific index to one colour, and another index to another.

I've tried quite a lot of combinations and they seem to only change the whole list colour instead of the index. I understand why because it's referring to the whole list, I just don't know how to change it for a specific index.

```
    m.aList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRender());

  private class MyCellRender extends DefaultListCellRenderer  
{    

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList list,  
            Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,  
            boolean cellHasFocus )  
    {  
        super.getListCellRendererComponent( list, value, index,  
                isSelected, cellHasFocus );  

        ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> complete = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> incomplete = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
            values.add(list.getModel().getElementAt(i));
        }

        for (Object o : values) {
           if (o.toString().contains("COMPLETED")) {
               complete.add(o.toString());
           }
           if (o.toString().contains("INCOMPLETE")) {
               incomplete.add(o.toString());
           }
        }

        for (String s : complete) {
            setForeground(Color.green);
        }
        for (String s1 : incomplete) {
            setForeground(Color.red);
        }

        return( this );  
    }  
}
```

The values in the list contain either COMPLETED, or INCOMPLETE, and I would like to change their colour according to their value.

Comment: Take a look at `ListCellRenderers`

Comment: I'm using a ListCellRenderer, this is a snippet of code that I'm trying to use to change the colour, however, it changes the colour of the whole list instead of the index I want

Comment: then post a full `SSCCE` of your code to show how the problem is occurring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The values in the list contain either COMPLETED, or INCOMPLETE, and I
>   would like to change their colour according to their value.

First off there's no need to keep these three lists:

```
ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> complete = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> incomplete = new ArrayList<>();
```

The [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) component is evaluated for each element in the [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) so these lists are pointless. You can implement your requirement easily doing as follows:

```
private class MyCellRender extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
       super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
       if(value.toString().contains("INCOMPLETE") ||  value.toString().contains("COMPLETED")) {
           Color fg = value.toString().contains("COMPLETED") ? Color.green : Color.red;
           setForeground(fg);
       } else {
           setForeground(list.getForeground());
       }
       return this;
   }
}
```

Take a look to [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) section in [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) trail for further details.

Comment: Thankyou very much, don't have much understanding as to how cell renderers work so I'll read up on it

Comment: @user1848712 you're welcome! Take a look to [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13673083/1795530) for a better understaing about how Swing renderers work.

Answer (score 1):

Youre setting the foreground color for every list component but `getListCellRendererComponent` is called when rendering every individual cell. In that case you need to do something like

```
if (value.toString().contains("COMPLETED")) {
    setForeground(Color.GREEN);
} else if (value.toString().contains("INCOMPLETE")) {
    setForeground(Color.RED);           
} else {   // handle default case
   ...
}
```

This is the only user code needed in the `ListRenderer`