# Align Rows to Right Side in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to align rows to the right side in a JTable?
In this picture, the rows are aligned to left, how can I align the rows to the right side?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408541/align-the-values-of-the-cells-in-jtable

Comment: Eventually some code could be helpful.

Comment: please can you show us how did you to set Component's Orientation, please post the code in the http://sscce.org/ form

Comment: should happen automatically ( @JanDragsbaek not a duplicate, the other is about aligning in a _cell_ while this is alignment of the complete table itself, actually looks like a problem with ComponentOrientation running wild somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution is to put your JTable in JScrollPane, and put this pane on plase of yours JTable and JTableHeader. JScrollPane will made everything for you without any headache.

```
yourPanel.add( new JScrollPane(yourTable) );
```