# Scala Swing Table Header

Tags: swing, scala

I'm having trouble centering and right aligning **table headers** in scala swing.

I can align text for the other data rows (by overriding the `rendererComponent` method in `scala.swing.Table` class).

The suggested way in java swing is to set a custom cellrenderer (e.g. [Align the values of the cells in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408541/align-the-values-of-the-cells-in-jtable)) to align cells, however this does not work in scala swing table...

Any help is appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most Scala-Swing components has `peer` property which gives you access to the underlying Java's Swing component. So I believe, that you just need get `table.peer` and then use solution you mentioned. More info you can find in SalaDoc:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/swing/Table.html#peer:JTable

Hope this helps.